# mysql query: get only those name_id which has 4 and 6 term_id attached to it

Tags: mysql

I have a table and data like this

```
id | term_id | name_id 
1  |   4     | 1
2  |   6     | 1
3  |   5     | 2
4  |   6     | 2
3  |   4     | 3
4  |   6     | 3
```

I want a query so that I can get only those name_id which has 4 and 6 term_id attached to it ... if i query 4,6,2 it should not display me anything because no named_id is attached to all three of them or like 4,5 it should not display anything because non has same 4 and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it (if i understand what you want):

```
SELECT t1.name_id 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.name_id=t2.name_id 
WHERE (t1.term_id = 4 AND t2.term_id=6) OR (t1.term_id = 6 AND t2.term_id=4) 
GROUP BY name_id;
```

When i run this query i get

```
+---------+
| name_id |
+---------+
|       1 | 
|       3 | 
+---------+
```

Comment: Same result as my answer. @user499703 what *do* you want then?

Comment: first of all i want to thank you for the great help... i just want that i want to get all data from name_id which has the same term_id as i want ..... like if i want a name_id which has 4 and 6 term_id it should so that term_id not when i search 4 and 6 and 2 which should not display anything

Comment: i only have term_id which i can use to get name_id

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name_ID
FROM Table1 t
WHERE term_id IN (4,6)
GROUP BY NAME_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: that is the "or" statement but i want some like and statement like show me name id with 4 and 6 not or 4 or 6 because if it put 4 and 6 and 2 it should not show me anything

Comment: This returns a name_id for two rows with same name_id and term_id both 4, `(1,4,2),(2,4,2)`. That's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      name_id
   from
      YourTable
   where
      term_id = 4 or term_id = 6
   group by 
      name_id
   having
      count(*) = 2
```

To clarify what is happening, you need to understand the "GROUP BY" and "HAVING" context.  Group by forces the SQL query to group as many qualified records by the columns it is identifying as the "Group By" clause.  This just happens to be the same single column in the query.

Next, the HAVING clause is based on the final results of the group after all records are pre-qualified and included.  In this case, it is looking at the COUNT(*) of records that qualified = 2.

Since you were concerned with a given Name_ID being associated with BOTH Terms of 4 AND 6, we want any names where their ID was found in BOTH... Hence the OR condition of the WHERE clause.  We want any record where a person was associated with 4 OR 6.  If at the result, only ONE record was found (only a 4 or 6), their COUNT(*) value would be equal to 1 and thus discarded from the result set... Only those that qualify with BOTH terms would have a count(*) = 2 and thus included in the final results...

To see otherwise what it may look like, try this query...

```
select 
      name_id,
      count(*) as TotalTermsPerName
   from
      YourTable
   group by
      name_id
```

You'll get all name ID with a minimum of 1 term, and others that could have 10 terms or more based on your data.  Since the original query was only considering the terms of 4 AND 6, the maximum count that COULD be reached would be a max of 2.

Hope this helps, instead of just a query answer and not understanding the basis of HOW things work.

Comment: that is the "or" statement but i want some like and statement like show me name id with 4 and 6 not or 4 or 6 because if it put 4 and 6 and 2 it should not show me anything

Comment: @user499703, see revised answer for clarification.

Comment: @Octopus-Paul... Thanks... missed it. dyslexic fingers...  yup, that's my excuse :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name_id
FROM t
WHERE 
  term_id = 4
  AND
  name_id IN (SELECT name_id FROM t WHERE term_id = 6)
```

Comment: sorry is not what i am looking for